# Running Stockfish chess engine under php script

Tags: php, bash, shell, chess

I'm thinking about making a php script which opens stockfish chess engine CLI, send fews commands and get back the output.
I think I can achieve this by using `proc_open` with pipes array but I can't figure out how to wait the whole output... If there's another better solution it's appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
// ok, define the pipes
$descr = array(

    0 => array("pipe", "r"),
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),
    2 => array("pipe", "w")
);

$pipes = array();

// open the process with those pipes
$process = proc_open("./stockfish", $descr, $pipes);

// check if it's running
if (is_resource($process)) {

    // send first universal chess interface command
    fwrite($pipes[0], "uci");
    // send analysis (5 seconds) command
    fwrite($pipes[0], "go movetime 5000");

    // close read pipe or STDOUTPUT can't be read
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    // read and print all output comes from the pipe
    while (!feof($pipes[1])) {

        echo fgets($pipes[1]);

    }

    // close the last opened pipe
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    // at the end, close the process
    proc_close($process);

}
```

The process seems to start, but the second STDINPUT I send to process isn't able to wait until it finishes because the second command produces analysis lines for about 5 seconds and the result it prints it's immediate.
How can I get on it?

[CLI link](http://abrok.eu/stockfish/), [CLI documentation link](http://download.shredderchess.com/div/uci.zip)

Please, ask me for more information about this engine if you need.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
fwrite($pipes[0], "uci/n");
fwrite($pipes[0], "go movetime 5000/n");
```

Without /n Stockfish see this as one command (ucigo movetime 5000) and don't recognise it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code works. $pipes[1] contained all the output from stockfish...

You might need to change the line

```
position startpos moves 5000
```

to a different number, as the 5000 means 5000 ms = 5 seconds, ie. the time when the engine stops. Try 10000 and the engine stops after 10 seconds etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove: `fclose($pipes[0]);` and make check for **bestmove** in while cycle, if **bestmove** is found - break the cycle, and after that only put `fclose($pipes[0]);`. That worked for me. And add **\n** separator at the end of commands.

Thanks for the code!